# Error in Spring Security core plugin while upgrading grails from 1.3.x to 2.0.4

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I have a app developed in grails 1.3.x and I upgraded to 2.0.4, There was an dependency error in the spring security plugin, so i did `grails install-plugin spring-security-core`, It installed 1.2.7.3 version. Then I ran the  grails application, I got the below error.

```
Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
C:\Users\Vinay.hs\.grails\2.0.4\projects\steer\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springs
ecurity\AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method saveException(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException)
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler
                        saveException(request, exception);
                        ^
```

Then I added `compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'`. I got a different error as below

```
:::: WARNINGS
                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: #spring-security-core;1.2.7.3: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://plugin
s.grails.org/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_2_7_3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom': bad organisation: expected='' found='o
rg.grails.plugins';

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
                grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://plugins.grails.org/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_2_7_3/spr
ing-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'
```

I referred [this jira issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-57), According to that we have to change the dependency to runtime, but it it was giving me the below error

```
    inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://plugins.grails.org/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_2_7_3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom': bad organisation: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins';
```

So, How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you put the dependency in the BuildConfig.groovy `dependencies` section but it should be in the `plugins` section:

```
plugins {
   runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
   build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
   ...
   compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'
}
```

Comment: I added the  compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3' line but its giving me the error Bean property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' is not writable or has an invalid setter method