# Unable to install spring-security-core.2.0-RC2

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I've gone over a number of answers to similar questions but I have still not been able to fix this problem. I have included the following in my BuildConfig -

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
}

repositories {
    ...
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone"
}
```

However, when I run the app it gives me the following error -

```
| Downloading: spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_2_0-RC2/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

    http://grails.org/plugins: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_2_0-RC2/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

| Downloading: spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_2_0-RC2/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

    http://grails.org/plugins: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_2_0-RC2/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

| Downloading: spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_2_0-RC2/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

    http://grails.org/plugins: bad organisation found in   http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_2_0-RC2/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- :spring-security-core:2.0-RC2
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I tried using install-plugin to add it manually but even that threw an error.

If its helpful, I am using the eclipse IDE for spring/grails and its a Grails 2.2.4 project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jar dependencies go in the dependencies block. Put plugin dependencies in the *plugins* block.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I actually just fixed this right now after stumbling onto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338824/error-in-spring-security-core-plugin-while-upgrading-grails-from-1-3-x-to-2-0-4